# How to put "Advanced form block" in a twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript

I want to add an [Advanced Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/afb) into a modal. So far I've been partially successful, the block is added to the modal but the form is outside the modal markup.

[image]

The area marked in red is the form which should be in the **div** with the class `modal-body`. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the [Advanced Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/afb), has a `CSS` class of `.node-form` and this is not encapsulated in the standard block content div `.block-content`. So when the [Twitter Bootstrap Modal Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter_bootstrap_modal) module tries to add the `.modal-body` CSS class to the `.block-contents` div, it will not find the div and the form will be left outside the modal body.

For me the easiest way to solve this was to edit `Twitter Bootstrap Modal Block` JavaScript file, i.e. `sites/all/modules/twitter_bootstrap_modal/twitter_bootstrap_modal_block/twitter_bootstrap/modal_block.js`, as follows:

Change the line that reads

`$(this).children('.block-content').addClass('modal-body'); //line 29`

to

`$(this).children('.block-content, .node-form').wrapAll('<div class="modal-body" />');`

This will put the `advanced from block` into the modal body.